# determining if a flash drive exists from a batch file without error messages

Tags: batch-file, file-exists, usb-flash-drive

I have batch files with the construct:

```
if exist F:\ copy /y Application.exe F:\
```

at the end of a compile, to copy the executable to a USB key if it is plugged in.  It has worked fine with USB keys but when I had a USB multi card reader plugged in (this looks like drives E:..H:, and if there is no SD card plugged in, when I execute the above batch line, I get a "Windows - no disk" snag message.

If there is a card plugged in, I don't get the message, (and the file is copied), if the card reader is not plugged in, I don't get the message and the file is not copied (obviously), but in neither of these cases does the batch file stop running.  It's only if the card reader is plugged in but there is no card in the drive.

Can I check quietly for no "disk" in these USB drives from a batch file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `IF EXIST` with `DIR` and use the `&&` or `||` depending on what you want to happen.

For example,

- To replace `IF EXIST...`

  ```
  DIR F:\ && copy /y Application.exe F:\
  ```
- To replace `IF NOT EXIST`

  ```
  DIR F:\ || copy /y Application.exe F:\
  ```

If You want to suppress the STDOUT and STDERR of the DIR to mimic the IF EXIST exactly...

- To replace `IF EXIST...`

  ```
  DIR F:\ 1>NUL 2>&1 && copy /y Application.exe F:\
  ```
- To replace `IF NOT EXIST`

  ```
  DIR F:\ 1>NUL 2>&1 || copy /y Application.exe F:\
  ```

Comment: Thanks @David.  Worked a treat.  Using the construct `if not exist F:\ echo hello` displays a dialog `---------------------------
Windows - No Disk
---------------------------
Exception Processing Message c0000013 Parameters 75b6bf7c 4 75b6bf7c 75b6bf7c
---------------------------
Cancel   Try Again   Continue   
---------------------------` if F:\ refers to a USB card reader with no card plugged in, whereas using `DIR F:\ 1>NUL 2>&1 || echo hello` just echos `hello` like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there used to be that you could run command.com with a `/F` parameter to make it always automatically fail those error messages so that it didn't break on them. Not sure about it though and not at all sure if that still works on modern Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`DIR` is ok only when the drive is not empty.

I no files exist on the drive it will not work even if drive is properly plugged in.

Use `CD`instead:

```
CD F:\ && copy /y Application.exe F:\
```

Answer (score 0):

`if exist` will work if you add `NUL` after `F:\`. Like this:

```
if exist F:\NUL copy /y Application.exe F:\
```